# VSTO: how to force Visual Studio to run a new instance of Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Visual Studio needs to run an instance of `EXCEL.EXE` to enable editing Excel worksheets in design mode from within Visual Studio. Unfortunately, instead of always running its own, if it finds one already running it will use that one. If that instance happened to be working, or running a macro for example, the macro will sometimes crash. And if for some reason I need to kill it (which I often do), it will obviously stop working in VS too.

The solution is to close ALL `EXCEL.EXE` instances, run VS, open the VSTO project, VS will then find no running instances of excel and run its own, and then I can re-open my previous instances. This is not always possible though, so I would like to find a way of making VS open a new instance every time.

Comment: BTW Is another solution (although not great) to start a new excel process and attach the debugger to it?

Comment: No, I am talking about VS's designer, at design time. I am not running any code, nor doing any debugging. VS needs an Excel.exe process for the designer and it steals any currently running process instead of creating a new one. That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a VB guy, so my code may be lacking (although it's just copied from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)).

First you want to declare a variable to hold the new Excel instance:

```
Excel.Application oXL;
```

Then you need to set the variable to a new instance and make it visible:

```
oXL = new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;
```

Then only refer to that instance in your code, e.g.,

oXL.Workbooks.Open ...

Comment: no no no, *I* am not creating this instance in code, *Visual Studio* is. When you open the spreadsheet editor in a VSTO project in VS, it needs to use an Excel.exe instance. This has nothing to do with user code from within the project. This is all in design mode, no compilation or execution has ever taken place yet.

Comment: my apologies.  I've tried to figure this out, but am stumped.  good luck.